# Shopify Scripts how do I show the discount on product page

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a script working and displaying the discount in the cart page but not on the product details page. The product also has varients so the discount would need to by dynamic.

With Shopify Scripts how do I show the discount on product page?

Thanks

Comment: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/discounts/sales

Answer (score 2):

You can't use Shopify scripts on products page, these are exclusive to cart and checkout page.

You can read more about it [Here](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/checkout-settings/script-editor)
[image]